# Doctrine 2: Eager load all associations in specific context?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to write a script to preload the mysql innodb buffer pool, so I would like to be able to just go through and load up some complex entities and have them eager load all of their associations.  Is there a simple way to do this, without having to manually set each association to eager fetch mode?